# How can I create a multi-level list menu from strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vbscript, hta

I am using vbscript inside an HTA to get a list of subnet locations and it returns text like the following:

- Chicago
- Denver
- Dallas
- Dallas/North
- Dallas/South
- Dallas/West
- Dallas/West/Building1
- Dallas/West/Building2
- Houston
- Sacramento/West
- Sacramento/West/Building1

I'm trying to dynamically create an unordered list so that I can use jquery to create a collapsible menu.

I can cycle through an array, but building the nested `<ul>`s and `<li>`s are seemingly impossible. I have the jquery ready once the list is actually built, but I can't seem to build it.

Is there any jquery that can do this for me?

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to properly ask questions. You need to show some code demonstrating you've made an effort. No one is going to write this for you.

Comment: I think part of my problem is this:  
When I'm adding UL tags with vbscript, they seem to be autocompleted by ...something.  

So I add Result.InnerHTML = "<ul>" but the contents of the Result div end up being "<UL></UL>".  

This is messing up my formatting. Anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: And I'm just asking if any one knows of a jquery function that already exists that does this. I'm not asking for someone to "write this for me."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where arrList is the list returned by the GetSubnetLocations function in the format above (alphabetized)

```
Dim arrMenu : ReDim arrMenu(-1)
Dim arrLocs : ReDim arrLocs(UBound(arrList),1)
i = 0
For Each x In arrList
    'Also building option list here
    intCount = Len(x) - Len(Replace(x,"/",""))
    arrLocs(i,0) = x
    arrLocs(i,1) = intCount
    i = i + 1
Next

Result.InnerHTML = ""

ReDim Preserve arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)+1)
arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)) = "<ul id=""menu"">"
For x = 1 To UBound(arrLocs,1) Step 1
    ReDim Preserve arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)+1)
    arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)) = "<li><a>" & " " & arrLocs(x,0) & "</a></li>"
Next 

For j = 1 To UBound(arrMenu)
    If arrLocs(j,1) > arrLocs(j-1,1) Then 
        arrMenu(j-1) = Replace(arrMenu(j-1),"</li>","<ul style=""display:none"">")
    End If 
    If arrLocs(j,1) < arrLocs(j-1,1) Then 
        For x = 1 To arrLocs(j-1,1) - arrLocs(j,1)
            arrMenu(j-1) = arrMenu(j-1) & "</li>"
        Next 
    End If 
Next 
ReDim Preserve arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)+1)
arrMenu(UBound(arrMenu)) = "</ul>"

strMenu = ""
For Each n In arrMenu
     strMenu = strMenu & n
Next
Result.InnerHTML = strMenu
```